# Use belongs_to association in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I am reading the docs, and they say about belongs_to:

> Specifies a one-to-one association with another class. This method
>   should only be used if this class contains the foreign key.

I have 3 models:

```
Info
Customer
Seller
```

I need that every instance of Customer or Seller can be linked to one row in the infos table.

So I think I just need to put the foreing_key info_id in the 2 models, and specify a `belongs_to :info` association.

But when I do this:

```
@customer.info
```

It gives me error because is trying to execute this query:

```
SELECT  `auth_infos`.* FROM `auth_infos` WHERE `auth_infos`.`customer_id` = 1 LIMIT 1
```

But for what I need and what I underatand from the docs it should execute this one:

```
SELECT  `auth_infos`.* FROM `auth_infos` WHERE `auth_infos`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Then use need to use [Polymorhic](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) , association

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like

info model

```
has_one :customer
has_one :seller
```

customer model

```
belongs_to :info
```

seller model

```
belongs_to :info
```

model having **belongs_to** always contain **foreign key**. So customer and seller table will have info_id foreign keys.

```
info_id
```

After that you can get both customer and seller linked with info and vice versa.

```
@customer.info
@info.customer
@seller.info
@info.seller
```

Comment: It doesn't seem right to me. I don't want to have 2 fields in my table.. If one day I decided to add 3 more model I would end up to 5 fields, with each row using only one of this.

Answer (score 0):

The docs express the relationship incorrectly. "Belongs_to" doesn't state anything about the cardinality of the *other* model, only that whatever the other model is, it can only have zero or one of whatever "belongs_to" it.

If ...

```
Price belongs_to Book
Book  has_one Price
```

... then a book can have zero or one prices, and a price can only belong to one book.

If ...

```
Price belongs_to Book
Book  has_many Price
```

... then a book can have zero or many prices, and again a price can only belong to one book.

If a Customer or a Seller can *optionally* have at most one Info, and onfo can have either zero or one Customer or Seller, then make Info polymorphic and let Customer and Seller "has_one informable" (or similar). Then Info "belongs_to informable"

Answer (score 0):

You can use polymorhic association. make Info model polymorhic.

info.rb

```
class Info < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :informable, polymorphic: true

end
```

customer.rb

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :info, as: :informable

end
```

seller.rb

```
class Seller < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :info, as: :informable

end
```

Comment: I ve  followed your solutions, but it keeps me searching for "customer_id" in info table, and not for informable_id!